# relative url regex not allowing space

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following regex to check for relative url there is a function that checks the url and returns true if its ok, the following works:

```
MyCustomPage.aspx?name=John&last=smith&type=Person
```

But the follwing when i have more than two words in the last name with a space separating them returns false

```
MyCustomPage.aspx?name=John&last=smith+connors&type=Person
```

See the +connors, this would not evaluate... but if i remove the check.. it goes through fine..

This is the regex

```
Regex IsRelative = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.[a-zA-Z/]*(((\?)([a-zA-Z]*=\w*)){1}((&)([a-zA-Z]*=\w*))*)?$");
```

in my function i check if the url is valid based on that regex

```
IsRelative(MyUrl)
```

I need it to let it pass if there is a space in there but i am not sure how.. anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: You're only accepting letters from **a** to **z** and from **A** to **Z**. You should accept numbers, **&**, **-**, **_** and **+** as well. *I beliebe* that `[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_\&]` will make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow plus signs (+) as the argument values:

```
Regex IsRelative = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.[a-zA-Z/]*(((\?)([a-zA-Z]*=[\w\+]*)){1}((&)([a-zA-Z]*=[\w\+]*))*)?$");
```

Here, I changed `\w` into `[\w\+]`, where the regex checks for argument values. With this change you will be allowing urls that have plus signs (+) at the right of the equal sign (=) of each argument.

Comment: I believe that you should allow numbers and other URL-accepted characters as well

Answer (score 1):

In your regex, you are using \w to match whatever comes after the = in the name/value pair. However, since you are dealing with a URL, you either need to decode it or account for the fact that + is not part of the \w character class.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html
This is a regular expression test page.

The catch with your issue, is that 'plus' is a reg expression reserved sign.
You have to place a 'backslash' to handle it.

^name=([A-Za-z]+)&last=([A-Za-z+]+)&type=([A-Za-z]+)$